# Successive calls to MPI_IScatterv with same communicator

Tags: c, mpi, nonblocking

I am trying to scatter two different, independent arrays from rank 0 to all others, over the same communicator, using non-blocking version of communication.

Something along these lines:

```
//do some stuff with arrays here...
MPI_IScatterv(array1, partial_size1, displs1,
             MPI_DOUBLE, local1, partial_size1,
             MPI_DOUBLE, 0, some_communicator, &request);
MPI_IScatterv(array2, partial_size2, displs2,
             MPI_DOUBLE, local2, partial_size2,
             MPI_DOUBLE, 0, some_communicator, &request);
//do some stuff where none of the arrays is needed...
MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
//do stuff with the arrays...
```

So... is it possible (or rather if it is guaranteed to always be error-free) to use two successive calls to MPI_IScatterv using the same communicator, or might that affect the result - mess up the messages from both scatters, since there are no tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to perform multiple non-blocking collective operations at once according to the [MPI standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf). In particular, on page 197, in section 5.12. NONBLOCKING COLLECTIVE OPERATIONS:

> ***Multiple nonblocking collective operations can be outstanding on a single communicator.*** If the nonblocking call causes some system resource to be exhausted, then it will fail and generate an MPI exception. Quality implementations of MPI should ensure that
>   this happens only in pathological cases. ***That is, an MPI implementation should be able to
>   support a large number of pending nonblocking operations.***

Nevertheless, make sure that different `request` are used for the successive calls to `MPI_Iscatterv()`. The function [`MPI_Waitall()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Waitall.3.php) is useful to check the completion of multiple non blocking operations.

```
MPI_Request requests[2];
MPI_Iscatterv(...,&requests[0]);
MPI_Iscatterv(...,&requests[1]);
MPI_Waitall(2,requests,...);
```

A sample code showing how it can be done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    MPI_Request requests[42];

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

    int size,rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

    int version,subversion;
    MPI_Get_version( &version, &subversion );

    if(rank==0){printf("MPI version %d.%d\n",version,subversion);}

    //dimensions
    int nbscatter=5;
    int nlocal=2;
    double* array=NULL;
    int i,j,k;
    //build a 2D array of nbscatter lines and nlocal*size columns on root process
    if(rank==0){
        array=malloc(nlocal*nbscatter*size*sizeof(double));
        if(array==NULL){printf("malloc failure\n");}


        for(i=0;i<nbscatter;i++){
            for(j=0;j<size*nlocal;j++){
                array[i*size*nlocal+j]=j+0.01*i;
                printf("%lf ",array[i*size*nlocal+j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

    }

    //on each process, a 2D array of nbscatter lines and nlocal columns
    double* arrayloc=malloc(nlocal*nbscatter*sizeof(double));
    if(arrayloc==NULL){printf("malloc failure2\n");}

    //counts and displacements
    int* displs;
    int* scounts;
    displs = malloc(nbscatter*size*sizeof(int));
    if(displs==NULL){printf("malloc failure\n");}
    scounts = malloc(nbscatter*size*sizeof(int));
    if(scounts==NULL){printf("malloc failure\n");}

    for(i=0;i<nbscatter;i++){
        for(j=0;j<size;j++){
            displs[i*size+j]=j*nlocal;
            scounts[i*size+j]=nlocal;
        }  

        // scatter the lines
        if(rank==0){       
            MPI_Iscatterv(&array[i*nlocal*size], &scounts[i*size], &displs[i*size],MPI_DOUBLE,&arrayloc[i*nlocal], nlocal,MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[i]);
        }else{
            MPI_Iscatterv(NULL,  &scounts[i*size], &displs[i*size],MPI_DOUBLE,&arrayloc[i*nlocal], nlocal,MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[i]);
        }
    }

    MPI_Status status[nbscatter];
    if(MPI_Waitall(nbscatter,requests,status)!=MPI_SUCCESS){
        printf("MPI_Waitall() failed\n");
    }

    if(rank==0){
        free(array);
    }
    free(displs);
    free(scounts);

    //print the local array, containing the scattered columns
    for(k=0;k<size;k++){
        if(rank==k){
            printf("on rank %d\n",k);
            for(i=0;i<nbscatter;i++){
                for(j=0;j<nlocal;j++){
                    printf("%lf ",arrayloc[i*nlocal+j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }

        }

        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    free(arrayloc);


    MPI_Finalize();



    return 0;
}
```

To be compiled by `mpicc main.c -o main -Wall` and ran by `mpirun -np 4 main`